# confused about v-model and select statement in vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following vuejs code:

```
       <select v-model='selectedInverter' class="custom-select" @change="changedInverter">
           <option>Select an inverter</option>
           <template v-for="inverter in localInverters">
             <option>{{inverter.display_name}}</option>
           </template>   
       </select>
```

If I `console.log(this.selectedInverter)` in my `changedInverter`, I get just the display_name and not the whole object. How do I capture (or bind) the whole object in v-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on this is here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

If you scroll down to the dynamic options section you'll see example code that will get you where you need to be:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
```

In your case, your `v-bind:value` data will be the entire `inverter` object, where the option text would be `{{inverter.display_name}}` as you already have in place.